# How to handle $http response in angularjs using jsreport?

Tags: angularjs, jsreport

I'm trying to integrate jsreport with angularjs project. I can post jsreport json data but do not know how to handle the reponse to render the jsreport in the browser. Anyone help me

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', [ '$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {
 var onSuccess = function (data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope.data = data;
   };
   var onError = function (data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope.error = status;
   }
   var datajson = {
    template:{'shortid':'S1Auk01mb'},
}
   var postReq = {
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'http://localhost:8005/api/report',
           data:datajson
       };
   $http(postReq).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
   var getReq = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8005/api/report'
        };
    $http(getReq).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your final get request to look like this:

```
$http(getReq)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(errorpayload => {
        console.log(errorpayload.data);
    });
```

You can then do what you need to with the data object from response. (I logged it out, so you can see what the data will look like.)

Comment: Okay. Thank you  I will do so. @jheimbouch